# Formulation of the Three-Body Newtonian problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, three-body-problem

I am trying to understand three body problem in Newtonian space. I want to make formulation of differential equations for known initial conditions for the case with:

1. Identical three masses
2. Periodic solution
3. Zero Angular momentum

The equations in vector form are:

$$\frac{d^2 \overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_1}{\text{dt}^2}=\frac{k^2 m_2 \left(\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_2-\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_1\right)}{r_{12}^3}+\frac{k^2 m_3 \left(\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_3-\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_1\right)}{r_{13}^3}$$

$$\frac{d^2 \overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_2}{\text{dt}^2}=\frac{k^2 m_1 \left(\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_1-\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_2\right)}{r_{12}^3}+\frac{k^2 m_3 \left(\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_3-\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_2\right)}{r_{23}^3}$$

$$\frac{d^2 \overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_3}{\text{dt}^2}=\frac{k^2 m_1 \left(\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_1-\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_3\right)}{r_{13}^3}+\frac{k^2 m_2 \left(\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_2-\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}_3\right)}{r_{23}^3}$$

where $k$ denotes the gravity constant.

I want to formulate (not solve) this problem properly.

I've found this reference can help [understand zero angular momentum](http://montgomery.math.ucsc.edu/papers/noSyzygies.pdf). I don't understand it well.

Comment: It is not clear what you're looking for.  You have the equations of motion, the only other piece is initial conditions.

Comment: ok, initial conditions but how to set them to satisfy periodic solution and angular momentum to be equal to zero

Comment: hope that it is clear what I am looking for. explain mathematically condition of angular momentum to be zero and periodic solution. for two body problem is solvable without these conditions

Comment: Finding periodic solution to the three-body problem is extremely difficult.  Very few such solutions are known, despite people working on the problem for hundreds of years.  In the last few weeks a [recent paper came out with the largest set of such orbits](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0181), but its not something you can trivially solve.

Comment: @ zhermes thank you for new comments. So the problem of two bodies is nonlinear in basis and then solvable analytically, am I right? I think that you are not right with momentum, this is not a strict condition because rotation of the center of mass should be equal to zero?

Comment: Yes, two-bodies is always solvable analytically.  And yes, I was **very** incorrect, sorry.  To design a zero angular momentum system, even, is non trivial. The easiest way to do so would be to move to the center-of-mass coordinate system, and set one velocity is depending on the other two - to cancel the net angular momentum, i.e. (assuming equal masses) $\vec{v}_1 \times \vec{r}_1 = - (\vec{v}_2 \times \vec{r}_2 + \vec{v}_3 \times \vec{r}_3)$

Comment: Can you give some suggestions how to set parameters or which conditions to apply to satisfy almost periodic or periodic solutions?

Comment: If there were simple rules for that, then it wouldn't such a difficult problem.